# Infinite Looping (Page Reload) Blues

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

What is it, about the code below, that would be causing the page I've successfully re-directed to, via the completeLogin() function, to continually reload itself?

More Context-

A user can log into my app through Facebook. After the user presses the button to initiate that, and authenticates through Facebook successfully, I then want the page that initiated the login, and which received the successful login information from Facebook, re-direct, to another vie, where the user can then complete the registration process for my application. As I mentioned above, the page is indeed being re-directed to where I need it to be.

The page just continues to reload itself because I know something is being called immediately and I need to know how to stop it.

Many thanks, 
CM

```
<script>
  // Called with the results from FB.getLoginStatus().
  function statusChangeCallback(response) {
  console.log('statusChangeCallback');
  console.log(response);

// The response object returns with a status field that lets the
// app know the current login status of the person.

    if (response.status === 'connected') {
  // User is logged into your app and Facebook.
    console.log("You are connected.");
    completeLogin();
    console.log("completeLogin called")
  testAPI();
} else {
  // The person is not logged into your app or we are unable to tell.
  document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
'    into this app.';
}
  }

  // This function is called when someone finishes with the Login
  // Button.  See the onlogin handler attached to it in the sample
 // code below.
  function checkLoginState() {
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
      statusChangeCallback(response);
    });
  }

function completeLogin()
 { location.href = '@Url.Action("ExternalLoginConfirmation", "Account")'; }

  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
  appId: '1614609378567893',
  cookie     : true,  // enable cookies to allow the server to access
                // the session
  xfbml      : true,  // parse social plugins on this page
  version    : 'v2.8' // use graph api version 2.8
});


   // FB.getLoginStatus() gets the state of the
  // person visiting this page and can return one of three states to
  // the callback provided:
  //
  // 1. Logged into your app ('connected')
  // 2. Logged into Facebook, but not your app ('not_authorized')
  // 3. Not logged into Facebook and can't tell if they are logged into
   //    your app or not.
  //
  // handles these three cases in the callback function.

  FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    statusChangeCallback(response);
   });

  };

  // Load the SDK asynchronously
  (function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

  // Running a simple test of the Graph API after login is
  // successful.  
  function testAPI() {
    console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
    FB.api('/me', function(response) {
        console.log('Successful login for: ' + response.name);
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML =
        'Thanks for logging in, ' + response.name + '!';
    });
  }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code is causing the page to reload:

```
location.href = '@Url.Action("ExternalLoginConfirmation", "Account")';
```

`location` is a variable on window which is always in scope. Changing this value triggers the user agent to go to that address you set the `href` property to. This is similar to a `window.location` redirect

```
window.location = "http://www.google.com";
```

In these situations it helps to just start removing snippets/lines of code until it stops behaving unpredictably.